# rails - how to translate what is within a ruby code in a form format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, internationalization, label, translation

I have a ruby code.

```
<%= f.label "Email *" %>
```

And I want to translate the English word "Email" to Japanese word because I am currently internationalizing my website written in English.

I tried the following.

```
<%= f.label "<%= t(:email) %> *" %>
```

However, it did not work. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `<% %>` within another `<% %>`. Write it like this:

```
<%= f.label "#{t(:email)} *" %>
```

Comment: Hi Uzbekjon, I wonder how I can translate what is written in the category. My current ruby codes are:                                                          <div><%= f.select :bs, "<option></option><option>To sell a property</option><option>To buy a property</option><option>To rent a property</option><option>Other inquiry or comment</option>".html_safe %></div>

Answer (score 0):

The `<%` tag already switches to ruby, where `=` also will render the outcome of the code. In order to get a translation, you might want to use `<%= f.label t("email") %>` and use email in your translation files.

As you need a translation inside a form, if it is bound to a model you can also translate your model as described inside the [translate your models section inside the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models). Then `<%= f.label :email %>` will translate out of the box.

There are several ways to mark required fields, you may simply do `<%= f.label "#{t("email")} *" %>` or style the required field via css, like:

```
# app/view/.../....rb
<%= f.label :email, class: 'required' %>

# app/assets/stylesheets/.../....css
label.required:after {
    content: " *";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am just wonder whether you know how to translate what is written in the options of the category in the form. My codes are currently:  div><%= f.select :bs, "<option></option><option>To sell a property</option><option>To buy a property</option><option>To rent a property</option><option>Other inquiry or comment</option>".html_safe %></div>

Comment: Translations can sometimes be a bit annoying, but you can find a lot of rails helpers that may become your friends. For those nested attributes you can use model/attribute, like [the gender example in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Comment: Not to forget, try to avoid html_safe, most of the time you really do not need it. In the code snippet you posted above, you may want to keep the possible options somewhere else (like a constant array in your model), so you can use that again for displaying somewhere else. Also it will be handy if you want to validate the given option is one of the choices you offered ([validates inclusion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion). Just think of what happens if someone adds another option in your html form and sends it to your application...